# USB wifi adapter not recognized (RTL8812BU)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I'm on 22.04.1 with kernel 5.15.0-56-generic.

I got this EDUP brand adapter because it said it was Linux compatible. It also said what its chip was. lsusb confirms it to be the chip:

> Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL88x2bu [AC1200 Techkey]

I plugged it in and nothing happened. After a reboot there was still no wireless network adapter detected in system settings. After some searching I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702). No errors. But after the reboot there's still no network adapter found by Ubuntu even though lsusb shows the device when plugged into different ports.

Where should I go from here? Could this be a secure boot issue? The instructions say it should be fine but I was asked to set a secure boot pw by the install script which was weird since I had already set it during the Ubuntu install.

> sudo modprobe 88x2bu && sudo dmesg | grep -i 88x2bu

comes up with:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '88x2bu': Operation not permitted

Comment: @Nmath Unfortunately no. I'm at the troubleshooting stage. I installed the driver the right way from the source recommended in the other post. Could this be a secure boot issue? It's enabled on my system. See updated post text.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe 88x2bu && sudo dmesg | grep -i 88x2bu`

Comment: @guiverc I've included the details.

Comment: "Operation not permitted" means Secure Boot issue. Does it work if you turn off Secure Boot?

Comment: @chili555 Disabling secure boot fixed it. Adapter was detected and I could connect to wifi network fine. Should I delete the post?

Comment: No need. It was closed for you. Glad it's working.